How to Change App Icon and App Name Dynamically Without Opening the App?
Google Play Console has a new feature called Custom Store Listings, which allows for different app icons and names. I want to dynamically change the app's launcher icon and name to match these custom listings when the user installs the app, without requiring the app to be opened.
I tried using , but it only changes the icon after the app is opened once and the app is restarted. How can I achieve this without needing the app to be opened?
androidmanifest.xml 

<activity-alias
    android:name=".MainActivityAlias1"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon1"
    android:label="@string/app_name1"
    android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity-alias>

<activity-alias
    android:name=".MainActivityAlias2"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon2"
    android:label="@string/app_name2"
    android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity-alias>

I use the following code to switch between icons:
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
ComponentName alias1 = new ComponentName(this, "com.yourpackage.MainActivityAlias1");
ComponentName alias2 = new ComponentName(this, "com.yourpackage.MainActivityAlias2");

pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(alias1,
    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(alias2,
    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

This approach requires the app to be opened and restarted to take effect. Is there a way to have the app's icon and name change dynamically upon installation without the need to open the app?

If you want to change app's icon dynamically without the requiring the user to open the app, above code alone isn't sufficient. You need to use some push-notification library like Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). Where, when you send a notification from backend, the app will receive it (no matter the app is currently open or has ever been opened before) and based on the notification, you can trigger the above code.
PS: For all this to work, your app should already have the activity-alias in the manifest with associated icon.
Update
Follow the steps below:

Add Firebase to Your Project
Add FCM to Your Project
Now, you'll have a class extending FirebaseMessagingService. In which, add following code:

override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
// Trigger the code you provided above to replace app icon here based on payload in remoteMessage
}


Finally, send a notification either using Firebase console or Admin SDK and this notification must have a payload.

The above image is from official docs, where you can see, no matter the app is in foreground or background, if your notification has a payload (data), it will always be delivered to onMessageReceived.


Could you please share some references or code related to to this? @dev.tejasb

@axita.savani have a look, I've added the supporting steps and code.

As per your steps, i have tried but still not getting any event or call from FCM before opening the app. When I open the app, FCM can register my device token and then send a notification. Then how it is works ?  @dev.tejasb

Actually, you should have a payload with the notification when you send it from backend either Firebase console or Admin SDK. I'll update the answer.
